# C++14 Can operator*= be constexpr? (Matrix class)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, constexpr

I have the following matrix class :

```
class mat4
{
public:
    constexpr mat4() noexcept;

    constexpr mat4(const std::array<float, 16> &m) noexcept;
    constexpr mat4(std::array<float, 16> &&m) noexcept;

    constexpr mat4(const mat4 &other) noexcept;
    constexpr mat4(mat4 &&other) noexcept;

    /*constexpr?*/ mat4& operator*=(const mat4 &other) noexcept;

    mat4& operator=(mat4 other) noexcept; // Uses std::swap

    constexpr float& operator[](size_t index);
    constexpr float operator[](size_t index) const;

private:
    std::array<float, 16> matrix;
};

constexpr const mat4 operator*(mat4 lhs, const mat4 &rhs) noexcept;
```

I would like to implement `operator*` with respect to `operator*=` like it is usually done with `operator+` and `operator+=`. The first argument is a passed by value to benefit of **copy elision**:

```
constexpr const mat4 operator*(mat4 lhs, const mat4 &rhs) noexcept
{
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

However, I see no way to implement `operator*=` as a `constexpr` function. Here is my implementation :

```
constexpr mat4& mat4::operator*=(const mat4 &other) noexcept
{
    std::array<float, 16> tmp; // The temporary is mandatory because the multiplication depends on the matrices *this and other.

    //matrix multiplication (three nested for loop to fill tmp)

    std::swap(this->matrix, tmp); // <-- ERROR: NOT CONSTEXPR
    return *this;
}
```

The other way I thought of doing it is to define `operator*=` with respect to `operator*` and write something like `*this = *this * other` in the body of the former. But then it would call `operator=` which is not `constexpr` because it also calls `std::swap` in his body.

Is there any way of making my `operator+=` a `constexpr` function?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you *need* to swap the two arrays? i.e. why not just `matrix = tmp;` which is perfectly fine in a constexpr function?

Comment: OTOH, many `std::array` member functions are not constexpr until C++17, so you may run into trouble because of that.

Comment: @melak47 Tell me if I'm wrong but my first thought was that `matrix = tmp;` performs a copy operation whereas `std::swap` a move operation (faster). But even with the former, I got this output using clang : `error : constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
1>  constexpr mat4& mat4::operator*=(const mat4 &other) noexcept `

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/558de4156956cd27

Comment: Pre-C++17 `std::array` doesn't mix well with `constexpr`. Use a native array or write your own `constexpr`-ified `array`.

Comment: "*The first argument is a passed by value to benefit of copy elision:*" That's not copy elision. You can't elide from a parameter to the function's return value.